# What is the Reason Of this Strange Behaviour of my Keyboard

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I have an Asus Rog laptop. I accidentally spilt soda on it a few months back. While the laptop itself has no problems right now, the keyboard is behaving very oddly. A few keys don't work and I know it is about the soda incident. What buffles me is that the keys that don't work normally **do** work with a strange condition. If I press another key and then press the broken key, they work. For example my "s" key doesn't work by itself. But if I press "d" and immediately press "s" it magically works. (It also works if I hold down "d") What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Well, first you short-circuited it, now it's corroded in random ways. Time for a new keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Corrosion, and now random signal paths.

It is possible that there is a PCB track that links the <kbd>s</kbd> and <kbd>d</kbd> as a common ground or signal which has been corroded or burnt out by whatever you spilt on it.

If the common ground signal is missing from the <kbd>s</kbd> key then pressing it will not be sensed as the track is broken.

When you press on the <kbd>d</kbd> key it either bend the board or flex or otherwise bridges the open track and makes a connection to the <kbd>s</kbd> key so that the controller can now "see" the key when it is pressed.

Your keyboard needs replacing.